# Google Wallet Subscription Free Trial with Initial Payment of 0.00 still Charging

Tags: android-pay

I've set up my `JWT` to submit a subscription with a free trial, however it still charges the account the recurring fee.

```
{ 
   "aud": "Google", 
   "iss": "11481745815237711699", 
   "request": { 
       "initialPayment": { 
           "paymentType": "free_trial", 
           "price": "0.00", 
           "currencyCode": "JPY" 
        }, 
        "name": "Automaton Scheduler Subscription (BASIC)", 
        "currencyCode": "JPY", 
        "sellerData": "user_id:9,subscription_id:4", 
        "recurrence": { 
             "price": "3000.00", 
             "frequency": "monthly", 
             "currencyCode": "JPY" 
         }, 
         "description": "Monthly subscription with up to 20 users." 
   }, 
   "exp": 1402563800, 
   "iat": 1402560200, 
   "typ": "google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1" 
}
```

Should this not skip the first payment, wait a month, then make a charge?
Am I missing something? Do I have to set the `startTime` manually? Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to manually set the `startTime` field for the `JWT` even though it is optional and `free_trial` is set. It uses a time stamp, so `time() + 2600000` will push it back one month. If it's not set, it will charge when the order is made.

https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#jwt